# What color would a bitcoin be if it had a color?

Tags: currencies

Of course dollars are green...

So what would the color of a bitcoin be if it had a color?

Comment: you guys are no fun

Comment: This is not a place for having fun. There are strict rules for asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

Orange... because all 'bitcoin' logo's..etc to date seem to be centred around orange.

Comment: I think it's meant to look gold